# Описание методов в отдельном классе или классе формы C#

Tags: c#

Если я создаю программу, которая читает данные с .xml документа, стоит ли кидать методы работающие со значениями из документа в отдельный класс? Методы вызываются при нажатии на кнопку, расположенную на форме. Или считаеться нормальным тоном описать методы в классе формы как статику?

Comment: Мухи - отдельно. Котлеты - отдельно. Форма - это представление, она только для вывода/показа данных. Бизнес-логика - в отдельных классах. / Всегда задавайтесь вопросом: могу ли я протестировать свой код с помощью модульных тестов (юнит-тестов)? Если напихаете всё в форму, то для проверки работы с xml придётся создавать экземпляр формы, а там могут быть тяжеловесные компоненты...

Comment: Начните с S в [SOLID (объектно-ориентированное программирование)](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 класс должен содержать 1 ответственность.

Классы форм должны быть максимально простыми и содержать лишь логику отображения, а вся бизнес-логика должна быть разложена по отдельным классам.

Конечно, если это какое-то очень простое приложение, то этим можно все пренебречь... Однако, по правилам хорошего тона все должно быть разбито на классы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.